# How to calculate the SPI and SPEI at each grid-level

Tags: r

I wanted to calculate the SPI and SPEI ***at grid-level*** using R software at timescale of 3 months.

```
library(SPEI)
spigrid<-read.csv("Data")

# I tried the following 
  
  for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
  if(grepl("X", colnames(data)[i]))
  spi[[i]]<-spi(data, 3, kernel = list(type = 'rectangular', shift = 0), distribution = 'Gamma')
}
```

I was expecting SPI at grid level at 3 timescale for each column of the grid but failed.